# Vite MPA with Vue plugin and TailwindCSS css not showing in build

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

another TailwindCSS/Vite question!

I have a website created that needs to have TailwindCSS working, however when I use `yarn serve` there is no CSS, at all. If I use `yarn dev` it works perfectly. No idea why this isn't working, if anyone can help that would be great :)

EDIT: More information is below:

File structure:

```sh
├── components
├── page1.html
├── page1.js
├── page1.vue
├── favicon.ico
├── index.css
├── page2.html
├── page2.js
├── page2.vue
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── public
├── page3.html
├── page3.js
├── page3.vue
├── src
├── tailwind.config.js
├── vite.config.js
└── yarn.lock
```

and here is my Vite config file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        page1: resolve(__dirname, './page1.html'),
        page2: resolve(__dirname, './page2.html'),
        page3: resolve(__dirname, './page3.html')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Another edit is that it used to work before, but I'm not sure what I changed to make it not show the CSS.

**Edit 2**: It got fixed, I think it was because the `purge` setting in my `tailwind.config.js` file wasn't set correctly.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @tony19 I added what I think was a good example, please let me know if you need more information :)